# How to configure nDPI for iptables

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, logging, protocol

I am new to **nDPI**, I have installed nDPI but when I add rules like;

`iptables -I OUTPUT -m ndpi --http -j REJECT`

It shows this error

```
iptables v1.4.7: Couldn't load match 'ndpi':/lib64/xtables/libipt_ndpi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Can tell me how to configure iptables for nDPI. I am using centOS 6.5

Comment: How did you made the ndpi module for iptables? did you use https://github.com/betolj/ndpi-netfilter

Comment: can you tell me how did u install ndpi??did u installed it in linux?

Answer (score 0):

It Seems you have not configured ndpi-netfilter properly. follow all the steps in my blog.
https://thingsinlinux.blogspot.com/2016/02/installing-and-configuring-ndpi.html
if one step fails, it will not work properly.